# Insert varchar coupon code in database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have a website based on reward point. I want to store the 'coupon code' in the database to a record which user has used which code to recharge their account to buy anything. I create an insert into table in `php` to insert the coupon for the user.

I encountered a problem that `INSERT INTO` sql syntax only insert the `int` code into database but when we use `VARCHAR` code to recharge account it is not storing any data...

Examples:

- `int coupon code: 22334466`
- `int coupon code: SU5C5E6S`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db_name="bs1";
    $con=mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("could not connect to mysql!!!");
    if($con=="")
    {
        echo "Database not connected!!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        $isdb=mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("database not available!!!!");
        if($isdb=="")
        {
            echo "database not selected!!!!";
        }
        else
        {   
            $emp_ID=$_POST['emp_ID'];
            $code=$_POST['code'];


            $query = mysql_query("select * from oc_abhi_reward where `Code`='$code'") or die (mysql_error());
            $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $code_db=$data['Code'];
            $points_db=$data['Point'];
            if($code==$code_db)
            {
            $query1 = mysql_query("select * from oc_customer where `emp_ID`='$emp_ID'") or die (mysql_error());
            $data1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
            $customer_id=$data1['customer_id'];

            $query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward` (customer_id, emp_ID,  order_id, description, points, date_added) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID,  0, 'rewarded', $points_db, NOW());");

            $query4=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward_history` (customer_id, emp_ID, description, Code, points) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID, 'rewarded', $code, $points_db)");


            $query3=mysql_query("DELETE FROM oc_abhi_reward WHERE Code='$code'");
            header("location:http://localhost/bsl/index.php?route=account/account");
            exit();
            }
            else
            {

            }           
        }
    }
}
?>
<!--php code for reward entry END-->
```

Comment: Hello Sandal, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the DDL of your table, e.g the structure of the table. Also post what you have attempted so far and try to be clear about what the issue you are facing is

Comment: sir My code of php to connect with database and insert data into table is here:

Comment: $query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward` (customer_id, emp_ID,  order_id, description, points, date_added) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID,  0, 'rewarded', $points_db, NOW());");

Comment: $query4=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward_history` (customer_id, emp_ID, description, Code, points) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID, 'rewarded', $code, $points_db)");

Comment: whats the error you get??

Comment: in the database table named oc_customer_reward all other data is inserted and code column is also inserted if code is in the format of 22334466 but if code format is SU5C5E6S then code is not inserted

Comment: Please edit your question and use the markdown for posting code. Code rendering in the comments is very bad

Comment: @sandal what is the data type of your code feild in Db??

Comment: @HugoTunius I think you mean edit the question.

Comment: no error massage shown... only when I use any integer numbers code to reward my account then it stored in database table otherwise code field left blank in database and other data is stored I m giving you the snapshot of database table..................

Comment: I do indeed @Barmar, thanks

Comment: type of database type in table is VARCHAR................

Comment: try with this 
$query4=mysql_query("INSERT INTO oc_customer_reward_history (customer_id, emp_ID, description, Code, points) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID, 'rewarded', '$code', $points_db)");

Comment: use single quotes at the start and end of $code variable

Comment: Thanks Sir but when I use single quotes at the start and end of $code variable it store the value in the table oc_customer_reward_hostory' column code but the value of coupon code is shown only 0 not the actual code that I use.

Comment: Thanks Sir is done now, I got the result when I change the $code with single quotes in the start and end in the table where all other Info I am getting about customer account recharge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$code should be write in single quotes , so the code for insert variable character codes in the database should be like this,

```
$query4=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oc_customer_reward_history` (customer_id, emp_ID, description, Code, points) VALUES ($customer_id, $emp_ID, 'rewarded', '$code', $points_db)");
```

Comment: I am facing a new problem in this. I found that sometimes the code is not update points in the users account but deleted from the table as I give the sql query           $query3=mysql_query("DELETE FROM oc_abhi_reward WHERE Code='$code'"); so now I want to know a sql query that inactive the code only when points are updated in the users account instead of being deleted from the list.